# Problema al enviar formulario a phpmyadmin haciendo uso de PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, input

estoy intentando realizar un formulario de tres input y que al presionar un boton este se envie a Phpmyadmin, pero no lo estoy pudiendo lograr, Soy nuevo en esto de PHP y estoy leyendo la documentacion a la vez que lo intento realizar pero no soy capaz de ver la falla.

Aqui va el codigo

```
    <?

if (isset($_POST["send"])){
    include ("../../connect.php");
    $nameC = !empty($_POST['nombreC']) ? $_POST['nameC'] : NULL; //Se define la variable utilizando los name de los input
    $emailC = !empty($_POST['emailC']) ? $_POST['email'] : NULL;
    $comment = !empty($_POST['comment']) ? $_POST['comment'] : NULL; 

    $sql="INSERT INTO datos VALUES ('$nameC','$emailC','$comment')"; //Sentencia SQL

    $eject=mysql_query($sql); //Se ejecuta la sentencia

    if(!$eject){ // Aviso de ejecucion
        echo"Fallo al enviar";
    }else{
        echo"Enviado con exito";

    }
    

?>
```

Los input:

```
<div class="caja">
    <form action="#" method="POST">
        <div class="BoxComments">  
                <input class="text" type="text" actionid="username"placeholder="Name" name="nombreC">
            <br>
            <br>
                <input class="text" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="emailC">
            <br>
            <br>
                <textarea  class="BoxComment" id="BoxComment2"type="form" placeholder="Comment" name="comment"></textarea>
            <br>
                <button  class ="ButtonComments"  href="index.php" name="send" type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Alguien es capaz de encontrar la falla? Muchas gracias a todos!

Answer (score 0):

Hola ten cuidado con las etiquetas php deben agregar al inicio <?php
te recomiendo que uses un editor de código como visual studio code.

Tu formulario modifique los nombres y agregue la conexión a la base de datos porque no veía tu archivo de conexión revísalo debería funciona bien.

```
<div class="caja">
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
        <div class="BoxComments">  
                <input class="text" type="text" name='user' id="user" placeholder="Nombre">
            <br>
            <br>
                <input class="text" type="text" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" name="email">
            <br>
            <br>
                <textarea id='comentario' class="BoxComment" placeholder="Comentario" name="comentario"></textarea>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Registrar" >
             
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<?php
    define('DB_HOST','localhost');
    define('DB_USER','root');
    define('DB_PASS','');
    define('DB_NAME','BD');

$conexion=@mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if(!empty($_POST['enviar'])){
    $nameC = !empty($_POST['user']) ? $_POST['user'] : NULL;
    $emailC = !empty($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : NULL;
    $comment = !empty($_POST['comentario']) ? $_POST['comentario'] : NULL; 
    $sql= "INSERT INTO demo VALUES ('$nameC','$emailC','$comment')"; 
    $ejecucion = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    echo "INSERTO CORRECTAMENTE";
} 
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Creo que el problema está en el formulario.

En la etiqueta form el atributo action debe hacer referencia al archivo php que procesa los datos.

Esto debería funcionar.

```
  <div class="caja">
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
        <div class="BoxComments">  
                <input class="text" type="text" actionid="username"placeholder="Name" name="nombreC">
            <br>
            <br>
                <input class="text" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="emailC">
            <br>
            <br>
                <textarea  class="BoxComment" id="BoxComment2"type="form" placeholder="Comment" name="comment"></textarea>
            <br>
                <button  class ="ButtonComments" name="send" type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, el PHP lo tengo en el mismo file que el del input. Asi que no es necesario

Comment: Entonces probablemente sea por la versión de php, si  está utilizando php 5 en adelante cambia `mysql_query` por `mysqli_query`. (https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: Lo cambie y tampoco funciona

Comment: Tiene que cambiar todas las funciones que inician con `mysql` por `mysqli`. `mysqli_query ($link , $query);`. Si eso no funciona debería revisar la estructura de su base de datos.

Comment: No comprendo, A que te referis con Link y Query_

Comment: Subo el post a ver si alguien logra ayudar